# Unable to get response from the library

Tags: node.js, wavesplatform, ride

I try to execute this code and receive current blockchain block number

```
nodeInteraction.currentHeight('https://nodes.wavesplatform.com/').then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

I did not forget to import the library

```
import { invokeScript, broadcast, nodeInteraction, waitForTx } from '@waves/waves-transactions';
```

This code is executed correctly.

```
nodeInteraction.accountData(dappaddress, baseUri).then((v) => {
    window.dAppData = v;
    if (v) {
        window.dAppDataKeys = Object.keys(v);
        console.log("dApp Account data:");
        console.log(v);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(v));
    }
});
```

I'm using below library

https://wavesplatform.github.io/waves-transactions/globals.html#currentheight

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I do not get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer) I forgot to re-build my React app. Sorry.